# Mysql запрос к прошлому периоду в одной таблице

Tags: mysql

Ребята подскажите как можно решить такую задачу.
Есть таблица
id - datetime - title(varchar) - summa(int)

Каждый день в эту таблицу поступают данные.
Каким образом можно сравнить сегодняшние данные со вчерашним днём?
Но при этом в сегодняшних данных может не быть например вчерашних строк, или же наоборот могут добавиться новые которых не было вчера.

Задача показать изменения в суммах и выбывшие или поступившие строки.
Mysql 5.6

Comment: пример данных в студию

Comment: Вывести разницу сегодня-вчера, вывести то, что меньше\больше, не выводить\выводить одинаковые - уточните вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.title, t2.sum, t3.sum
FROM      (
           SELECT title
           FROM `table`
           WHERE `date` > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 2 DAY
          ) t1
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT title, sum
           FROM `table`
           WHERE `date` = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ) t2 ON t1.title = t2.title
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT title, sum
           FROM `table`
           WHERE `date` = DATE(NOW())
          ) t3 ON t1.title = t3.title
```

Comment: Вот примерно данные.

# вчера
1 - 2017-04-23 - Возвраты от покупателей - 200
2 - 2017-04-23 - Расходы на топливо - 100
3 - 2017-04-23 - Выручка за смену - 400

# сегодня
4 - 2017-04-24 - Возвраты от покупателей - 700
5 - 2017-04-24 - Выручка за смену - 300
6 - 2017-04-24 - Собственные нужды - 100

В итогде хочется видеть, что сегодня Возвраты от покупателей выросли на 500, Расходы на топливо исчезли но появились Собственные нужды.
Реальных данных у меня нет, это учебная задача, на стадии обдумывания уже третий день.

Comment: Я не понял... что, предложенное решение не даёт нужного результата?

Comment: @AndreyKoftun Решение задачи надо начинать с того что бы придумать подходящие данные и написать, что должно на основе этих данных получиться в ответе. После этого только приступать к написанию запроса. И пока вы эти данные не приведете в вопросе, никто не поймет что на самом деле вам нужно